# Is there a quick-save shortcut?

Tags: pc, deus-ex-human-revolution

Is there a quick-save and/or quick-load shortcut in Deus Ex: Human Revolution?

Comment: I had this same problem when I started playing. The keys are not re-bindable, so they don't show up under the game controls screen (which is irritating).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes there is in fact.

Pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> will quicksave the game, and pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> will load the quicksave.

Comment: And don't worry, F8 shows a nice little confirmation dialog asking you if you are sure you want to Quickload and lose your current game progress. I love the UI in this game, they really thought it through.